# IAM Policy for Sanbox Enviornment

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam, aws-security-group

I am looking to provide a separate sandbox environment for my users. A concept similar to GCP Projects. Requirements are:

- Each user should have only access to his own resources.
- User should not be able to see the resources of other users.
- Users should be able to create overlapping resources e.g user1 can create a VPC with 10.1.0.0/16 and user2 should be able to create the VPC with 10.1.0.0/16.

If there are any other options besides IAM, I am happy to opt.

Comment: In your case its easy. Its not possible to make  a sandbox with your requirements, unless you create separate account for each user.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve these goals, you should provision a separate AWS Account for each user.

Each Account can be linked back to a master account using AWS Organizations.